# Why don't fenced code blocks in Markdown appear in a monospace font when Doxygen generates HTML?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

When I run the following through Doxygen

```
~~~{.cpp}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   printf("Hello world!\n");
}
~~~
```

The HTML output has the expected C++ syntax highlighting but the font is no different from normal text. Do I need to specify a font in the Markdown source? If so, how do I do that? Is this something that would be remedied by updating Doxygen? I'm using v1.8.5.

Comment: The 1.8.5 version is quite old (August 2013) the current version is 1.818.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I extend the example slightly to

```
some main text<br>
~~~{.cpp}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   printf("Hello world!\n");
}
~~~
```

and run it with doxygen I see that  the font-family (in FireFox) for "some main text" is "Roboto, sans-serif;" and for the code this is "monospace, fixed;" (as seen by inspect element).
This is the case for 1.8.5 as well as for the current version 1.8.18. The 1.8.5 version is quite old (August 2013).

You can manipulate the fonts etc by using `HTML_STYLESHEET` or better do overruling with `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`. See the doxygen manual:

- http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_stylesheet and http://doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_stylesheet
- http://doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#minor_tweaks_header_css

Comment: That worked! I just had to change the font family under `div.line`